# UIImagePickerController to show only videos

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to have the UIImagePickerController only show the videos on the phone and not both videos and photos? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `mediaType` property of the `UIImagePickerController`.

```
//Example from documentation
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

or to simplify the documentation's example with newer syntax:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[kUTTypeMovie];
```

More information and guidance is available in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes).

Comment: Worth mentioning you need to `import MobileCoreServices` otherwise Xcode won't find type kkUTTypeMovie